# How can I change innerHtml without affecting a tag that is in it?

Tags: javascript, html

this is the inner html I wish to change (1.1k):

`<a id="js-fb-1" href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i> 1.1k</a>`

This is my js code:

`document.getElementById("js-fb-1").innerHTML = string;`

However, it removes the i tag that is also within the anchor tag. I have tried

`document.getElementById("js-fb-1").innerHTML = "<i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>"+ string`

but it doesn't work. How can I keep the i tag and only change the number?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the result you're trying to get?

Comment: Is 1.1k hardcoded in the HTML and is this solved with `string.replace("1.1k",newvalue)`? How is 1.1k being added into your JS?

Comment: If any of the answer helped you, you should mark it as the answer. That way it will help others

Answer (score 3):

All content in HTML is generically known as a "node" and all nodes have a [`nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType), which is a number defining what kind of content it is. Text nodes are `3`, so if you loop over all the [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) of the `<a>` and look for a `nodeType` of `3`, you've found raw text and can change its [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent), not [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) (which should be avoided when possible due to its security and performance issues).

```js
// Get a collection of all the child nodes in the <a>
// Nodes can be elements, attributes, raw text, comments, etc.
let nodes = document.querySelector("a").childNodes;

for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++){
  // Check for a text node
  if(nodes[i].nodeType === 3){
    nodes[i].textContent = "Something new";
  }
};

console.log(document.querySelector("a").outerHTML);
```

```html
<a id="js-fb-1" href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i> 1.1k</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

First get the inner html than add what you want inside of the outer html

```js
let a = document.getElementById("js-fb-1");
let inner = a.innerHTML;
inner = inner.replace(a.text, 'example'); // removes text but keeps the html
a.innerHTML = inner;

console.log(inner);
```

```html
<a id="js-fb-1" href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i> 1.1k</a>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: `.innerHTML` is irrelevant to this question. If you are going to go the `.replace` route, just use `const a = document.getElementById("js-fb-1"); a.textContent.replace("1.1k", 'example');`

Answer (score 0):

It's best to add a span around the text that you want to be able to replace. Than you can select that nested element and replace its contents, without disturbing everything around it.

```js
let string = "2.3k";
document.querySelector("#js-fb-1 span").innerText = string;
```

```html
<a id="js-fb-1" href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span>1.1k</span></a>
```